# Mirth destination missing response

Tags: mirth

I have a Mirth destination calling a channel with a JavaScript writer. When I view the child channel's response in the event viewer I can see it is sending the appropriate JSON object but when I view the messages of the calling channel it shows an empty message returned from this destination.

Shouldn't a destination channel be able to send a message payload back up to the calling channel? Or am I missing something obvious.

Here are the channel messages for the called channel. I can see that there is a response value.
[image]

Here are the channel messages for the parent channel. The destination response is empty.
[image]

Here is the final statement from the JavaScript Writer Destination in the child channel. (there are no additional transformations)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your downstream channel, on the source tab, make sure you select the Javascript writer destination in the Response dropdown if that is what you want to return to the upstream channel as your response. It's probably set to none.